# How to convert nodejs "import" and "require" to regular JS to work in a browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

can you please tell me how to turn nodejs code into regular JS code?

For example:

```
import {Apis} from "graphenejs-ws";
var {ChainStore} = require("graphenejs-lib");
```

Is there a standard way to convert imports and requires into regular javascript?

I'm trying to get the project example in the README to work in a browser, but I don't know how to convert the import and require to use the browser JS: `https://github.com/svk31/graphenejs-lib/blob/master/build/graphenejs-lib.js`

can you help me get import and require from nodejs into the equivalent regular JS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/):

> Browsers don't have the require method defined, but Node.js does. With Browserify you can write code that uses require in the same way that you would use it in Node.

Comment: I want to use the code in a browser only, not in nodejs. I tried browserify with the file api.js from some source: http://pastebin.com/dcJ6Pew8, and then ran it browserify to get bundle.js which has the nodejs code turned into: http://pastebin.com/MQyLHYib and yes I still can't use the nodejs code in javascript because I am in a browser.... I just want to be able to code in the browser, and not in nodejs. Why is this so complicated to do?

Comment: @KrNel Ever figure this out?

Comment: I learned nodeJS @jkupczak ;) Now I code with the new ES standards.

Answer (score 0):

There are no import and require method for the client side, you must import the package on a script anchor.
use Browser to fetch the package locally

https://bower.io/

Or import directly the link via :

https://cdnjs.com/

Comment: In another module: ```https://github.com/svk31/steemjs-lib```, the code ```var {Client} = require('steem-rpc');``` was turned into ```var Client = window.steemJS.steemRPC.Client;```. Is there no simple way to convert nodejs code to regular JS? bower.io uses more nodejs, I just want to use regular javascript to call the browsered js file above ```graphenejs-lib.js```....

Answer (score -1):

Plugin scripts can be loaded directly from a CDN per [hint at dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/loading-into-browser), then used to extend the main object.

The following uses [jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com), the same approach should work with other CDNs if they store plugins, make paths available and reveal where they put them once loaded. There's an example below using [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com).

These examples use dayjs and extend it to use custom parse formats (it doesn't support custom formats by default).

```js
let date = '10/01/2023';
let parseFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
let outputFormat = 'D MMM YYYY';

// Before loading customParseFormat, dayjs ignores the
// parse format and parses the timestamp as m/d/y
console.log(dayjs(date, parseFormat).format(outputFormat));

// Add the plugin
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat);

// Now dayjs sees the format and parses the timestamp correctly
console.log(dayjs(date, parseFormat).format(outputFormat));
```

```html
<!-- main script -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<!-- plugin -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
```

[cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com) example:

```js
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat);

console.log(dayjs('10/01/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY').format('D MMM YYYY'));
```

```html
<!-- main script -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.10/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<!-- plugin -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.10/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
```

You might also be able to use [require.js](https://requirejs.org), but couldn't get it to work in the limited time I had available.

Comment: Plugin scripts? Dayjs? Did you post this answer to the wrong thread?

Comment: @Bergi—dayjs was just an example. I thought the OP was after how to use resources typically loaded using import and require directly in a browser. If I'm wrong about that I'll delete the answer.